# windows 11 reduce system font size beyond builtin minimum

Tags: windows-11, display-settings

Title says it all: Win 11's minimum display font size is absurdly  huge.  Is there any way to adjust this via Registry settings?

Comment: Need more info : What are your computer and display adapter models? What is your display adapter driver? At what resolution is your screen? What is your Scale at *Settings > System > Display*?

Comment: @harrymc  The only thing that matters is that I have the  system settings slider set to minimum.   I want to make the OS feed any driver of any display smaller font (and incidentally ribbon icon) sizes.

Comment: Instead of reducing the text, you can enlarge everything else, which is why I'm asking.

Comment: 100% this is a scaling issue. Harrymc speaks the truth.

Comment: @spikey_richie  He speaks truth but not an answer.  There's a difference.  I don't want to make **anything** bigger. What would be the point to that?    So again, why can't we scale things down lower than the putative "100%" shown in Win 11  settings?  FWIW yes my monitors are at their highest display resolution settings

Comment: I would like to know how to reduce the font size below the slider minimum. Already at 100% scale, text size slider at bottom, fonts are too big for my liking. On earlier versions of windows could set individual font sizes for system fonts.